# Problem with SQL query in Java - Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble executing a *SQL* query in *Java* that works fine in *MySQL* but doesn't work in *Oracle*. Here is my query:

```java
String verifyLogin = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LoginDB WHERE username = '1234' AND password = '1234'";
```

The problem is that this query always returns `0` even though there is a record in the Oracle database with `username = 1234` and `password = 1234`.

I checked a few things:

The query is identical in code for both databases (*MySQL* and *Oracle*), I made sure that the usernames and password are exactly the same as in the query, and I have the appropriate permissions to query the `LoginDB` table in *Oracle*.

Is there something that may be specific to the *Oracle* database that causes this behavior? Do I need to adjust the query syntax or something else to make this work?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you try to add alias for the table and try one more time? `String verifyLogin = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LoginDB l WHERE l.username = '1234' AND l.password = '1234'";`

Comment: Hhmm... did you also added alias in front of columns `username` and `password`? I think Oracle does not know, which username you want to compare - from the system or from the table.

Comment: Have you tried the query on the oracle DB directly? It's a shorter way than with intermediate java ... ?

Comment: Yes I have tried this in SQLDeveloper, in MySql Workspace, also I added alias.

Comment: oracle only runs the query with out problems when you double quote the coumns see https://dbfiddle.uk/bUk4xsop

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data in both databases so that we can replicate the problem. If you do not tell us how you are storing the data and how you are creating the data then we can only guess at why there are differences between the two RDBMS.

Comment: @nbk The OP's query works without errors with unquoted identifiers. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T3Xx88R2)

Comment: @ITstudent and which result do you have in the SQLDeveloper? Also, interesting result for simple queries `SELECT * FROM LoginDB l WHERE l.username = '1234' AND l.password = '1234'` and `SELECT * FROM LoginDB l WHERE l.username = '1234'`

Comment: It also works for me, the query is identical but it doesn't work in the program, could it be connecting to the database via the network?

Comment: What @MTO reports would make me think your fields *username* and *password* are INTEGER?

Comment: fields username and password are varchar2

Comment: @ITstudent because in the Oracle word `username` is keyword from the system, and Oracle does not know, what exactly you want to compare in the `WHERE` part

Comment: Interesting. What do you see from a "select *" instead of "select count"?

Comment: A given user with login and password

Comment: @ITstudent if you think, that case of issue on the java-side, maybe it will be good, if you put some java-code in the question? I am not sure, how you execute SQL-query in your source code, and how extract result.

Comment: Ok guys thank you, i just had to restart my sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you `COMMIT` your data.

In Oracle, if you do not `COMMIT` then only the session where the the data was created can see the uncommitted data and other sessions, even those belonging to the same user, will never see that uncommitted data.

For example, the behaviour can be explained:

1. If you create the data in SQL*Plus but do not `COMMIT` the data or close the session.
2. Then if you query the data from Java then it will connect to the database and create a new session (even if you connect as the same user) and then you will never see the uncommitted data.
3. But if you go back to the open session in SQL*Plus then you will see the data exists in its uncommitted form in that session.
4. To see it in other sessions, `COMMIT` the data.